# Bubbling errors from c++/clr to c#/.net

Tags: visual-c++, exception, c++-cli, clr

I have the following code begin ran in a native/win32 c++ library.

```
// Load lt dll
OutputDebugString(L"LoadLtDll");
m_LTDll = LoadLtDll("C:/Program Files/Enciris Technologies/LT101 Driver H264/bin/encirislt_h264.dll");
if( !m_LTDll ){
    OutputDebugString(L"Library encirislt_h264.dll not found!");
    throw new std::exception("Library encirislt_h264.dll not found!");
}
```

I need the std::exception to bubble up the message to a .NET application.

It shows up in .NET as a SEHException, but without the message I passed to it anywhere. I need this messages to be bubbled up to .NET. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot make this work, there's no binary standard for C++.  Their object implementation is too heavily tied to the specific compiler vendor and compiler version to permit interop.  Standard .NET interop solutions with C++ are based on COM, C or C++/CLI.  The former two use error codes, the latter allows translating C++ exceptions to managed exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a c++/clr dll in between your native c++ code and the c# code, you could catch the native exception and throw an appropriate .net exception.